# How to read from stdin in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stdin

This is my code:

```
#open
mov $5,%eax
mov $file,%ebx
mov $0,%ecx
int $0x80
mov %eax,fd

#read
mov $3,%eax
mov fd,%ebx
mov $buff,%ecx
mov $8,%edx
int $0x80
```

it works, but I have to read the name of the file from the terminal.
(I have to do something like: `$./myProgram fileToRead.txt`)
How can I change my code? I try with:

```
mov $0,%ebx
```

but it doesn't work..

```
/usr/bin/ld:text.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:text.txt:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How do you assembly and link your assembly? What is the file name of the assembly file?

Comment: @fuz `gcc -o myProgram myProgram.s` and than `./myProgram fileToRead.txt`

Comment: You do not want to read the file name from stdin, you want to read the (rest of the) command line. I have no idea how to do that on your platform (Linux?), but reading from stdin won't cut it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/) is some linux 32b NASM article about command line arguments (I didn't check the content, just first google search hit which looks relevant) ... uh, and you are using GAS syntax, not Intel, so you need to adjust any code, but maybe just reading the information and ignoring code will be enough to help you. EDIT: and I don't see how changing `mov $file,%ebx` `mov $0,%ebx` would produce that error message, that looks completely unrelated, like you added `fileToRead.txt` to linker command line by mis.